# AVAudioRecorder throws errors

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, avaudiorecorder

I use `AVAudioRecorder` to record, it worked fine on iOS 4 devices, but yesterday we found out recording is broken on iOS5. Using the iPhone 5 simulator I got following error:

> 2011-08-02 11:09:03.586 Moodle[7832:10103] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Do you know where this error came from and how to fix this?

Comment: Your original question didn't ask how to fix it, it only asked for others to confirm if they had the same problem too — we didn't want that kind of stuff to be posted as answers and clogging up the question unnecessarily. Your edit has made the intent of your question much clearer now though so I've reopened it.

Comment: you can refresh [this question][1],use device test your code.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290418/avaudioplayer-error-loading-file

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This error is just console noise from a System framework, you should ignore it, it doesn't affect you. If your app is crashing or failing to record the real reason is elsewhere.

AVAudioRecorder works just fine on iOS 5, even if it does throw (and catch) Exceptions during normal operations which make debugging harder.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I had Xcode set to break on exceptions, and was wondering why my video player was crashing!

Comment: Oh, it affects me all right. It affects me the same way spam effects my inbox: by noising up my information stream, making useful messages harder to find. Logs should be clean. Spam should be eliminated. This bug should get fixed.

Comment: hooleyhoop: "AVAudioRecorder works just fine on iOS 5, even if it does throw (and catch) Exceptions during normal operations which make debugging harder." - I'm not sure I agree with your definition of "works just fine".

Answer (score 11):

I have also been experiencing these errors since moving to iOS5. I am not recording, but playing back sounds with AVAudioPlayer. This seems to be a problem with the AVAudio frameworks when using the iOS simulator only. Testing on actual hardware (an iPad 2 & iPad 1, in my case) does not produce these same errors, which makes me less concerned since testing on hardware is what I consider the testing that actually counts.

BTW, sorry that this is not an solution to fixing the issue, so much as a confirmation that you are not the only one experiencing the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I have found that this error only comes up when using the Simulator. When it is tested on an actual device it works fine and no errors come up.

So until Apple releases a bug fix for the Simulator, test your apps on devices.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to leave your break points on all exceptions in (which I find very useful), you can just use an if(!TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) statement before running audio.  This will cause audio to only run if you're using a device.

There won't be any sound from the simulator, but it's very helpful if you don't need music on and want to debug other code.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by deleting exceptional breakpoints.

Comment: on the left side of xCode vindow find "breakpoint". Choose all items and rightClick - delete;

Comment: Indeed, if you have exception breakpoints enabled for debugging purposes, this ignorable message is raised as an error and simulator stops. Removing the exceptions solves the problem until a fix for the simulator arrives.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error. It's only an expectation of breakpoint. This issue is occurring if you have add "expectation breakpoints" in your XCode. Main suggestion is - do not you "expectation breakpoints" in Cocos2d projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a real device to test you code, and wait for the next update. I think that is your best choice.