# iOS - Failed to play audio file

Tags: ios, mp3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play an mp3 audio file on iPhone executing the following code:

```
    NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@.mp3", FONYK_FILES_URL, [self.voicenote valueForKeyPath:@"Fonyker.fonykid"], [self.voicenote valueForKeyPath:@"Voicenote.vnid"]]];
    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3", [self.voicenote valueForKeyPath:@"Voicenote.vnid"]]];
    [audioData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&error];
    [audioPlayer play];
```

When it reaches the AVAudioPlayer instantiation it outputs this in the debugger:

```
2012-03-15 17:08:51.531 Fonyk[13004:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-03-15 17:08:51.544 Fonyk[13004:10703] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

Can't find anything related, any idea what's happening?

Comment: Have you added the required frameworks? Is this MP3 in a valid iOS format?

Comment: Yes the framework is added. And I believe mp3 is a format in itself, does there have to be something special for it to work on iOS ?

Comment: Some evil extension or compression algorithm... :) Have you tryed playing it using "audioUrl" (instead of cloning the file)?

Comment: Yes, then I learned you can't do that, AVAudioPlayer expects a URL that starts with file://

Comment: Why not use "initWithData:error:"?

Comment: Any chance of your problem is a duplicate of this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290418/avaudioplayer-error-loading-file

Comment: Seems to be the same thing Eduardo, seems it's a simulator problem, guess I'll have to try and deploy to a device and check it, thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this gdb output mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961840/what-does-this-gdb-output-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating AVURLAsset and asynchronously loading it's tracks as described in the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW15).  In the completion block you can create an AVPlayerItem and pass that to the player.

According to [AV Foundation Release Notes for iOS 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/_index.html), starting in iOS 5 the player should load the tracks if they are not already loaded.  In my experience, however, this doesn't work.  Manually loading them works so that's what I do.

Comment: Got the same error, it has to be as Eduardo referred, it's a simulator problem. Thanks for this anyways, I'll check back when I'm able to run on the device.

Comment: I am able to play mp3 files in the simulator.  Another minor difference:  I am using AVPlayer instead of AVAudioPlayer but I doubt that that is the issue.  Best of luck.

Comment: Mind posting the code you use here? See if there's any difference. I just coded it up as it's shown in the guide.