# Error as music is about to play in iPhone app

Tags: xcode, testing, audio, logging

I got this error in the log while trying to test some music that I want to play when the app opens:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

What does this mean and how would I fix it?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

From an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906930/avaudiorecorder-is-broken-on-ios-5) This is apparently an iOS5 issue which occurs on the Simulator only and can be ignored. It's annoying though.