# AVAudioFoundation upgrade to iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

I am using AVAudioFoundation. Got some problems with it on iOS 5.0 Simulator and on iOS 5.1 devices. The app works fine on devices and simulator with iOS 4.1.

1. There are loading errors on startup. They go on and on, like this:

   `Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _CFXMLNodeGetInfoPtr
   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
   Expected in: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security`

   I would think it had something to do with that I am running Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard and only downloaded the iOS 5.0 sdk instead of buying Lion and upgrading Xcode to 4.3. But then again, the problem appears on device too, so it does not seem to be a problem with Xcode.

   In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906930/avaudiorecorder-is-broken-on-ios-5) they say that this is just "noise". But could this still be the problem?
2. And then when calling `AVURLAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys: completionHandler:`, the `AVKeyValueStatus` is `0` instead of the expected `AVKeyValueStatusLoaded`.

Here's the code I use for that:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"duration", @"tracks", nil]];
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:tempRecFileURL options:nil];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler: ^{

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
    switch (tracksStatus) {
        case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
            // this is where I normally end up doing stuff but not on iOS 5.0
            break;
        case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
        case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
            // doing other stuff here
            break;
    }
}];
```

And here's the output I get (iOS 5.0 only):

```
[AVAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:] invoked with unrecognized keys (
        (
        duration,
        tracks
    )
).
```

`error` is `nil`.

What did I not get here? It feels like I need to make some reference somewhere, but I do not know where to.

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem here is the line

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"duration", @"tracks", nil]];
```

which should be

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"duration", @"tracks", nil];
```

Comment: That helped for iOS 5.0 but broke it for iOS 4.1.

Comment: How did it break? That method expects an array of keys, not an array containing an array of keys. There must be some other problem if it's not working on 4.1.