# strange behavior with "Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable" error

Tags: ios, avfoundation

So I've read a few posts regarding this and also am having trouble/strange behaviour with AVAudioPlayer.  Both of the following attempt at the method create the error (quoted at the end) but the audio actually plays with the first one.  With the second attempt, no audio plays.  Strange.

Audio plays with this, where "audioPlayer" is declared as an IVAR:

```
-(void) URplay:(UserRecording *)recording {
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioData error:&error];
   [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Audio doesn't play with this, where 'audioPlayer' is instantiated in the method:

```
-(void) URplay:(UserRecording *)recording {
   NSError *error;
   AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioData error:&error];
  [audioPlayer play];
```

}

Here's the error code:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn: dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.424 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.471 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.482 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.504 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
2012-06-28 21:07:08.514 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.533 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

2012-06-28 21:07:08.551 My Life: the Musical[6151:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable

Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVAudioRecorder is broken on iOS 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906930/avaudiorecorder-is-broken-on-ios-5)