# AVAudioRecorder - Proper MPEG4 AAC Recording Settings

Tags: ios, ios5, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I've got a live app with an estimated 15% of users reporting that the record feature is not working.  This isn't happening on our test devices, but the reports show that the problem is that prepareToRecord is returning NO.  I've had trouble finding sample settings for AAC format.  Are any of my settings off?  App requires iOS5 and uses ARC.

```
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityHigh], AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
 [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
 nil];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.caf", verseGUID, bRecordingReference ? @"_ref" : @""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[Utilities sharedInstance] documentsDirectoryPath], fileName]];
NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];
if([audioRecorder prepareToRecord]){
    [audioRecorder record];
}else{
    int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig([error code]);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])", [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this app on all the devices that currently support iOS 5? Maybe this problem is hardware-related?

Comment: We've had the problem reported on iPhone 4s, iPod Touch 4th Gen and iPhone 3GS, but it's not effecting other users on these same devices.  We've tested on iPhone 4s, iPhone 4, iPod Touch 4th Gen and iPad 1 and haven't been able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This crashes in the sim.

Comment: My understanding is that you should only test on the devices since they use entirely different audio hardware.  I've also seen several reports of problems with the audio recording and playback in the Sim with iOS5 as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906930/avaudiorecorder-is-broken-on-ios-5   However, if you see a specific setting that you believe may be causing the problem with the Simulator and the Devices, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it could be many things not having to do with the recording settings.

the real question you want answered seems to be: what would cause the recording not to occur?

audioRecorder could be nil or audioRecorder prepareToPlay could be returning NO.  the former seems more likely.

the url passed to initWithURL could be malformed:
- have you tested by playing with the verseGUID, bRecordReference values?  maybe your devices never have a bad verseGUID, but the devices on which no recording happens have a nil/empty verseGUID.  this could cause the filename to be simply ".caf".

you seem to have your own class method [Utilities sharedInstance] .  could this work for some reason on your devices but not on the failing devices?  if so, you could be asking to record in a top level directory when you did not mean to.

can you get the testers you have onto a "beta" list?  sign up for something like TestFlight or Hockey Kit, get one or more of the users with a failure to record to also sign up, and then upload a beta of your app with diagnostics that put a dialog on screen with the resultant "error".  that might be most obvious.  i use testflightapp.com only because it was the first i tried, it was pretty easy for me to manage and pretty painless for my beta testers.

Comment: +50 for TestFlight recommendation and because the bounty period has expired.  I'd still love it if someone could confirm that my recording settings are valid.  Apple's documentation on these is incredibly lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this settings which i used to record MPEG 4 AAC format...Its working good..

```
NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.m4a"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                  nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  This is the type of response I was looking for, however, I'm a little confused by some of these settings.  Why is there a LinearPCM property specified when recording AAC?  Also, a Bit Rate of 16 doesn't seem to make sense.  Wouldn't that be a value for the bit depth?  My understanding that the Bit Rate is in bits per second.

Comment: I do not know how much we need to give for bit rate and all. I just had a working code with this setting and i just gave it for you simply.

Comment: May be i need to go through the documentation for these settings for myself too.

Comment: That's just it, Apple doesn't provide helpful documentation for these settings.

Comment: I tried these settings on iOS 7, and the `AVEncoderBitRateKey` setting made the recording fail silently (it would output an empty file with just the headers in it).
I ended up using these settings: `@{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMin), AVSampleRateKey: @16000.0, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1};`

Comment: @Ahti, your settings saved me :)

Answer (score 2):

Apologies that this is slightly tangential but I've just had a very similar issue with a number of users not being able to record, which I thought was related to audio settings.

However for me it turned out that they had denied permission to access the microphone. This meant that `prepareToRecord` was working (and truncating the file) and `record` was reporting that it was working, but actually it wasn't recording anything.

And I used this when I want to record:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
    if granted {
        // can record - create AVAudioRecorder here

    } else {
        // can't record - update UI (or react accordingly)
    }
})
```

Hope it saves someone some time if they run into a similar issue.