# i want the size for 5 minutes 300kb for an audio file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I am attaching what I implemented to record the data, it is saving in `.wav` formate, But my problem is that file is taking too much of size (i.e for 10 seconds it is taking 86kb), I want the size for 5mints 300kb, I tried so many ways, can you please help me?

```
- (IBAction) startRecording
{
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    err = nil;
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }


recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NX_BigEndian == NXHostByteOrder()] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:0] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
recorderFilePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abc.wav"] ;

    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath: %@",recorderFilePath);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];


    err = nil;

    NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url path] options: 0 error:&err];
    if(audioData)
    {
        NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        [fm removeItemAtPath:[url path] error:&err];
    }

    err = nil;
    recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
    if(!recorder){
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        UIAlertView *alert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: [err localizedDescription]
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate:self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (! audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                   message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                  delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [cantRecordAlert show];

        return;
    }

    [recorder record];
 currentTimeUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                              target:self selector:@selector(updateAudioDisplay)
                                                            userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];


}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Wav format is not compressed. I think you need some framework or library which can convert .wav to .mp3 or another compressed format. But I do not know about such frameworks.

Comment: The WAV format is an uncompressed format. As such the size is in direct relation to the amount recorded. The only way to change the size is the change the quality of the recording, i.e. change the sample rate.

Comment: as like @zakhej told, .wav is not compressed and it's bit rate is too high.if you don't prefer .wav,go for other like .mp3,.mp4 and so.

Comment: check this link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 You can convert Audio from wav to mp3.

Comment: ok... Thank u so much  @zakhej, Vedchi , Johan Karlssson

Comment: You're recording uncompressed audio (linear PCM). With your settings (8 bits/sample, 1 channel, 8000 Hz sample rate) each minute of audio will require about 469 kB. To reduce the size of the recording you'll have to record into some kind of compressed format, such as AAC. You can find examples of settings to use if you search StackOverflow (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347760/avaudiorecorder-proper-mpeg4-aac-recording-settings))

Comment: The key AVSampleRateKey change the sample rate, which affect the quality of the recording and it´s size as well.

Comment: which framework or library we can use to convert  @zakhej

Comment: for the `.wav` format, you should use some combination of the `AVSampleRateKey` and `AVNumberOfChannelsKey` and `AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey`, which if you do multiply by each other, then the result is not greater than `8192`. NB: you will get a really sh@t quality audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format id to either **kAudioFormatAppleIMA4** or **kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC**. These will produce smaller sized audio files. WAV as mentioned in comments is an uncompressed audio format. So the audio file would be huge in size.